# Adding tooltips & legend in network diagram in R, igraph

Tags: r, igraph

I'm building a couple network diagrams using iGraph, and am having trouble adding a legend and tooltip.

I've included repro code below which builds a network successfully, but have yet to figure out the right way to do the following:

1: A tool tip to show a label (test_net$from_industry).

- I'm using tool tips because in the real network there are too many nodes to show the labels without visually overlapping.

2: A legend that shows color mapping of nodes to test_net$from_industry

```
library(igraph)
library(tidyverse)

test_net <- data.frame( 
  to = c(13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13),
  from = c(26, 33, 47, 85, 86, 91),
  id = c(0,1,2,3,4,5),
  to_industry = c("Water", "Steam, air-conditioning", "Irrigation systems", "Sporting goods", "Hobby & toy stores", "Religious organizations"),
  from_industry = c("Test1", "Test2", "Test3", "Test4", "Test5", "Test6"),
  value = c(23, 23, 21, 21, 19, 20)
)

test_network <- graph_from_data_frame(d=test_net, directed=F) 
plot(test_network, vertex.size=test_net$value*.5, vertex.color=test_network$from_industry, vertex.label=" ", layout=layout.random, main="Random")
```

Any advice on how to best go about this would be great. Thanks in advance.

[current output without legends / overlay labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QAMW.png)

Comment: Quick clarification, I don't want to hardcode the colors for the legend, as there's ~30 of them in the read df.

Comment: Why do you need to load `visNetwork`, `networkD3`, and `tidyverse`?

Comment: @CJYetman  I had loaded those just to play around with different network packages - will remove them from the post since they're not related to the Q. Thanks for calling out